# Cart summary drop down in top link

Tags: checkout, cart, customer

In my top links i have my account, basket(cart) and contact us.

What i would like to do is when an item gets added to the cart by the customer:

- the customer stays on the page they are instead of redirecting to the cart
- and a drop down appears under the cart link in the header displaying "you have $number item/s in your cart" with a link to the cart page.

The redirection i sorted in the admin configuration. But im not sure on how to do the drop down for the cart link in top links. I ideally want it to look like this:

[image: Cart example]

I only want it to do this when there are items in the cart though. When there inst any in the cart the link should look like normal

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an Ajax Mini Cart. I believe Enterprise edition has something like the out of the box, and I have worked with a custom built extension in the past.

There are a few in Magento connect that do similar to what you described.

Sort of like a mix of these: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/header-mini-cart.html 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-5.html